# jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut not working

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make a popup div come up when a link is clicked to display some content.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Popup Content Script
    $("#services").click(function(){

        servicesPopup();

    });

    $(".popupClose").click(function() {

        closePopupFunction();

    });

    function servicesPopup() {

        $(".popup").fadeIn("slow", function() {

            $(".container").css("opacity", ".3");
            $(".popup").html("This is a test.\n\
            This is a test.\n\
            This is a test.\n\
            This is a test.\n\
            This is a test.");

        });   
    };

    function closePopupFunction () {

        $(".popup").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".popup").html("");
        $(".container").css("opacity","1");


    };

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <li><a href="#" class="button" id="services" title="Learn about all of our services."><span>Services</span></a></li>
```

Nothing is happening when the button is clicked. I have tried every way I could think to alter both the code and the HTML to no success. I have done a search here and found nothing along with a complete look up of all the jQuery code and can not find an answer. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Write these functions `servicesPopup()` and `closePopupFunction ()` outside the `document.ready function` and then try.

Comment: @RohanKumar - There's no need for that, they're in scope where they are.

Comment: Joe - where's the html for `.popup` and `.container`? Your code as shown should do _something,_ even if the fade and so forth aren't what you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/b23Yz/ (I invented some html to match your JS, but put the close event on a document click rather than on whatever `.popupClose` is.)

Comment: N, I made the changes to reflect exactly what you have in your jsfiddle and I am still getting absolutly nothing for some reason. I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: None. I'm using chrome and checking everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function servicesPopup() {
    $(".popup").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(".container").css("opacity", ".3");
        //Also write the string in a single line or escape it
        $(".popup").html("This is a test.<br/>This is a test.<br/>This is a test.");
    });   
}

function closePopupFunction () {
    $(".popup").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".popup").html("");
    $(".container").css("opacity","1");
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    //Popup Content Script
    $("#services").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        servicesPopup();
    });

    $(document).on('click',".popupClose",function() {
        closePopupFunction();
    });    
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this matters but I am using WAMP.